# Testing if a matrix is MDS?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

In the Wikipedia page that explains the concept of an [MDS matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDS_matrix), the following condition for a given $m \times n$ matrix being MDS is mentioned: it is MDS if and only if all the square sub-matrices of $[I_n \vert A^T]$ are invertible (i.e. non-singular).

My question concerns implementation: given that for even moderately sized matrices the number of sub-matrices quickly grows, how should I implement it? I'm using SAGE, but I doubt that is the most adequate platform... More to the point, how to I avoid that, for example, once I start running the test code, it won't stop because it has exhausted the computer's memory?

(Of course if there are any other less intensive tests for this, I would appreciate learning about those as well!)